# Unable to install Sikuli

Tags: java, python, pip, sikuli

I can't get PIP to install Sikuli.

I googled this issue, and I saw some sites saying to add the following directorys to my System variables.

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1  
JRE_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271
```

And these to my PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin
```

So those should be correct. Other than this I couldn't find any other solutions.

I already updated pip and setup tools.

This is the full error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Marco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gefwt25k\\sikuli\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Marco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gefwt25k\\sikuli\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-6svrs62_'
         cwd: C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gefwt25k\sikuli\
    Complete output (44 lines):
    WARNING: Skipping page https://github.com/kevlened/pyjnius/releases/download/v1.1/jnius-1.1-dev.win32-py2.7.exe because the GET request got Content-Type: application/octet-stream.The only supported Content-Type is text/html
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Marco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-q3cmrzpa\\jnius\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Marco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-q3cmrzpa\\jnius\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-0b1bl_8i'
             cwd: C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-q3cmrzpa\jnius\
        Complete output (7 lines):
        'readlink' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-q3cmrzpa\jnius\setup.py", line 121, in <module>
            raise Exception('Unable to determine JRE_HOME')
        Exception: Unable to determine JRE_HOME
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\Marco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp8pfcre2v', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kevlened/pyjnius/releases/download/v1.1/jnius-1.1-dev.win32-py2.7.exe', 'jnius>=1.1-dev']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gefwt25k\sikuli\setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\Marco\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp8pfcre2v', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kevlened/pyjnius/releases/download/v1.1/jnius-1.1-dev.win32-py2.7.exe', 'jnius>=1.1-dev']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

Comment: is you pip and setuptools up-to-date?

Comment: Forgot to mention but yeah. I saw that on some other site so updated those and tried again.

Comment: Do you have more than one python version installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems to get the same error. It looks like the easiet way is to download the exe file from https://pypi.org/project/sikuli/#files and run it.